# Fetching a one to many relationship using Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, relationship, one-to-many

iam a swift beginner, i wanna code a little app for me and i have a problem with it. My app has three entities (Templates, Records and Positions), here you can see:

[Datamodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxJ3I.png)

At one part of the app i can add new Records and for that Record i add some Positions (xpos and ypos).

At a part I have a tableview were i list my Records. Now i wanna click one Record in the table and i want to get all Position-Attributes linked with the particular selected Record.

With that code i can get **all** xpos-Positions but how can i get a **single** xpos? :)

```
guard let moc = self.managedContext else {
   return
}

let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Records> = Records.fetchRequest()

do {
   let searchResults = try moc.fetch(fetchRequest)
   let xpos = searchResults[0].positions?.mutableArrayValue(forKey: "xpos")
   print(xpos)
} catch {
   print("Error with request: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into using `NSPredicate`.  `NSPredicate` basically lets you define the conditions which the record needs to meet to be included in the results.  Think of it as a filter if you will.

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uniqueID = %@", arugments:...)
```